# How to display like this format in PHP

Tags: php, php-deployer

i want to display my data like this format, please any one help me, Please please

1. Name     : Richard
2. Duration : 22nd - 27th August 2016
3. Event    : MS Project

Previous Event Details :

```
  S/N  | Event          | Duration 
 ----- | -------------  | ------------ 
  01   | VB project     | 12th - 15th December 2015
  02   | ARM min Project| 1st - 7th April 2000
```

## i'm totally new here please anyone help

Comment: I think you should visit this first
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Dave  thank you i will

Comment: You could, at least, try to be a little clearer. If you had provided enough information rather than just a vague intro to your *wants*, certainly the SO Community would (as always) help. But how can one help if he doesn't know  anything about what you wish to accomplish? At the least, you could have given more hints, data, & information. That way, you are guaranteed to get Help.

Comment: @Poiz Definitely i will try to give more information about it,  first i want to learn how to ask here, anyway thank you for your time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think giving some more information about what you try to archieve and what you already have would be better for the response. Could you maybe tell if you already getting the data, how you are getting the data(format).

Its simple if you are using a framework like laravel, in controller fetch the data from the database, afther that return the response view with the data included. In the response view you could the loop trough the results and echo them. But as i said before i have no clue about the way you are developping this.

Comment: Mr @Bolivir thank you so much your valuable reply, i hope it will help for me

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer